# Bean parameter could not be found when migrating spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm migrating services from spring boot 1.5 to spring boot 2.1 and I'm getting an error during this process. I have the following class for configuring my spring beans:

```
@Configuration
public class CompanyTransactionConfiguration {
    public CompanyTransactionConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionTaskRunner transactionTaskRunner(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new TransactionTaskRunnerImpl(this.readWriteTransactionTemplate(transactionManager), this.readOnlyTransactionTemplate(transactionManager), this.newReadWriteTransactionTemplate(transactionManager));
    }
}
```

And, of course, a test class to check that everything work as expected:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ReferrerActivityRepositoryIT extends AbstractDomainIT {

    @Autowired
    private ReferrerActivityRepository referrerActivityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTaskRunner transactionTaskRunner;

    ...
}
```

The issue is that this test was working fine after I changed my dependencies to a newer spring boot version (2.1), but now I'm getting the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method transactionTaskRunner in com.company.core.server.config.CompanyTransactionConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'transactionManager' in 'DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
    - Bean method 'kafkaTransactionManager' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix) did not find property 'spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix' 

...


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' in your configuration.
```

I don't know what is going on, maybe I need to add another dependency because of changes in spring boot or change my `application.properties` file. The question is why is this happening? What should I change to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define `PlatformTransactionManager` bean. I assume you don't want to make it  by yourself. You have to add `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix` property to property file in order to use KafkaAutoConfiguration for PlatformTransactionManager.

> - Bean method 'kafkaTransactionManager' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix) did not find property spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix

By the way your's  CompanyTransactionConfiguration constructor is redundant as long as it doesn't have parameters. If there's no constructor in class compiler will create default one without parameters.